# CocoaPods Error installing FLatUIKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, cocoapods

So i installed cocoapods and also crated a Project into which i intended to install a framework to it using CocoaPods but i get this error

[image]

I specified in the pod Insert:

```
 platform :ios, '7.0'
 pod 'FlatUIKit 1.3'
```

and then went back to the Command line and used "pod install" 
so as i thought it would install i got this seemingly error like text on screen as shown in the Picture.

How would i do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'FlatUIKit', '~> 1.3'
```

Also you may want to read this:

http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: Awesome, This works aswell, tried a similiar article and i also deleted that 1.3 from the Pod itself. Thank you!